# Count amount of times a value is represented

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have some code that takes input numbers and put them into a new array. How can i make it so my alert tells the user how many times the number is represented in the input? Exampel 0,4,4,2,3,4,1 would show "0 appears 1 time, 4 appears 3 times" and so on...I think im close but cant get the final part right...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Oppgave 5</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
  window.onload = btn;

  function btn() {
   document.getElementById("btn").onclick = showTxt;
  }

  function showTxt() {
   var text = "";
   var input = document.getElementById("input").value; 
   var split = input.split(",");
   var newArray = split;
   var count = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    if (newArray[i] === parseInt(input)) {
     count++;
    }
    alert("Number " + newArray[i] + " appears " + count + " times");
   }
   text += newArray;
   document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = text;
  }

 </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="input" type="text">
<button id="btn" type="button">Show</button>
<p id="print"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your showTxt function

```
function showTxt() {
  var text = "";
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value; 
  var split = input.split(",");
  var newArray = split;
  var count;
  for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    count = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < newArray.length; j++) {
      if (newArray[i] === newArray[j]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    alert("Number " + newArray[i] + " appears " + count + " times");
  }
  text += newArray;
  document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the method from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ralphcrisostomo/3141412) like so:

```js
window.onload = btn;

function btn() {
  document.getElementById("btn").onclick = showTxt;
}


function showTxt() {
  var text = "";
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var split = input.replace(/ /g, '').split(",").sort();
  compressArray(split);
}


function compressArray(original) {
  var compressed = [];
  // make a copy of the input array
  var copy = original.slice(0);

  // first loop goes over every element
  for (var i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {

    var myCount = 0;
    // loop over every element in the copy and see if it's the same
    for (var w = 0; w < copy.length; w++) {
      if (original[i] == copy[w]) {
        // increase amount of times duplicate is found
        myCount++;
        // sets item to undefined
        delete copy[w];
      }
    }

    if (myCount > 0) {
      var a = new Object();
      a.value = original[i];
      a.count = myCount;
      compressed.push(a);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < compressed.length; i++) {
    var message = compressed[i].value + ' appears ' + compressed[i].count + ' times.';
    alert(message);
    document.getElementById("print").innerHTML += message + '</br>';
  }
};
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
<button id="btn" type="button">Show</button>
<p id="print"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, may be it'll helpful .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Oppgave 5</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
  window.onload = btn;

  function btn() {
   document.getElementById("btn").onclick = showTxt;
  }

  function showTxt() {
   var text = "";
   var input = document.getElementById("input").value; 
   var split = input.split(",");
   var newArray = split;
      let countedValues = newArray.reduce(function(obj,val){
        if(obj[val])
          obj[val] += 1;
        else 
          obj[val] = 1;
        return obj
      }, {})
   for (let value in countedValues ) {
    alert("Number " + value + " appears " + countedValues[value] + " times");
   }
   text = newArray;
   document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = text;
  }

 </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="input" type="text">
<button id="btn" type="button">Show</button>
<p id="print"></p>
</body>
</html>
```